# Some documents in my mongodb collection exists but cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
// schema

const chapter = new Schema({
  version: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    default: "kjv"
  },
  bookTitle: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    lowercase: true,
    required: [true, "Book Title is required"]
  },
  chapterNo: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    lowercase: true,
    required: [true, "Chapter Number is required"]
  },
  verses: [
    {
      type: String,
      index: true,
      text: true,
      sparse: true,
      unique: true,
      required: [true, "Verses are required"]
    }
  ]
});

// my documents are in this manner

books = [
    {
      bookTitle: "leviticus",
      chapterNo: "chapter-1",
      verses: [
        'array of verses'
      ]
    },
    {
      bookTitle: "leviticus",
      chapterNo: "chapter-2",
      verses: [
        'array of verses'
      ]
    }
]

// till the end


mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb://path|url/name",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
  )
  .then(resp => console.log(`[Mongodb Server] started`))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
// @ts-ignore
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

Chapter.insertMany(books)
  .then(docs => {mongoose.disconnect();
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  
  
// this is how i query
Chapter.find({
  version: req.query.vrsn.toLowerCase(),
  bookTitle: req.query.bk.toLowerCase(),
  chapterNo: { $in: requests }
 })
  .select('-_id chapterNo bookTitle version verses')
  .then((docs) => {
   if (docs.length > 0) {
    return res.status(200).json({
     request: docs
    });
   }
   res.status(422).json({
    message: '...'
   });
  })
```

I have over a thousand collections of documents, these documents where saved to db using the same schema. I could retrieve all except documents with a specific field (bookTitle) value (leviticus). All documents with this field and value exist in the database but return empty when queried as if they are not there. Also, in my user schema i also have a field (role) and i have it specified when saving at first it works just fine but suddenly it started disappearing. all fields specified in the schema are provided during save and all shows in the db except role: 'regular' || 'admin'

Comment: You must show us some more code. Is impossible to do any kind of debugging based on this.

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages.

Comment: There's likely a typo, rogue space, or casing issue in either the document or the query. Can you update your question to show the document you expect to find with that query?

Comment: So I've edited it... @catajohn

Comment: Hi, I thought about unnecessary spaces and I began search for them, in the end I found 24 of them and correct them. The issue has been fixed now. Thanks all the way